# How do i add name attribute in mat-option material angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, material-design, angular-material2

How do i add name attribute in mat-option ?

```
<mat-option class="mat-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" ng-reflect-value="[object Object]" ng-reflect-id="someoptionValue1" tabindex="0" id="someoptionValue1" id="someoptionValue1" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="mat-option-text"> Ocean-LCL (NVOCC) </span>
<div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple="" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLElement]">
</div>
</mat-option>
```

If it is not possible to add name attribute in mat-option, Is there any alternation know property to mat-option ?
I used [id]="optionBindingValue" in mat-option tag

```
<mat-option [id]="optionBindingValue">{{optionBindingValue}}</mat-option>
```

but this "ID" attribute is displaying 2 times in inspect element. this [id]="optionBindingValue" is replaced the dynamic ID attribute value.

Is there any chance to remove one ID ? or adding name attribute?  or any alternative solution?

Comment: I would perhaps first ask what you are trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new component which extends the mat-select class, then add the desired fields to it. check the below:

`export class CustomMatSelectComponent extends MatSelect{
  public name:string;
}`

hope that helps.